# How to add an AM/PM option at the end of a custom cell format?

Tags: vba, excel

In order to allow for quick time entry, I have a custom format of

0":"00

so that entering 516 will result in 5:16. This works fine but I'd like to add whether it is in AM or PM.

I've tried adding AM/PM to the end of this custom format

0":00 AM/PM

so ideally, it would display as 5:16 PM if the cell was filled in in the PM. Unfortunately, it only ever shows AM, regardless of what time it was entered.

Does anyone know how I can get this functionality? Maybe a custom format isn't the option I'm looking for?

Comment: You probably require a worksheet_change that applies the correct custom number format depending on the time of day. Of course, you could always just use real time and then you wouldn't have to worry about minutes in base 10.

Comment: With your format applied, is better to work in 24 hour format

Comment: There is a standard time format for it (AM/PM with 24h format entered), why use a custom one?

Comment: @UGP - *'In order to allow for quick time entry,...'*

Comment: @Jeeped Yes I'll resort to using real time if necessary, just didn't know if there was an easy way to fix this AM/PM problem. The exact time to the minute matters in my case, but it isn't necessarily entered in real time is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Say we are entering values in column **A**.  If we enter:

```
516
```

in **A1** and it is morning when we make the entry, we want Excel to convert the value to:

```
5:16 AM
```

If it is afternoon when the entry is made, we want the value to convert to `5:16 PM`

Place the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim trail As String, v As String
    With Target
        If Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        If .Value = "" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                .Clear
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Exit Sub
        End If

        trail = Right(CStr(Now()), 2)
        v = .Text
        mins = Right(v, 2)
        hrs = Mid(v, 1, Len(v) - 2)
        If trail = "PM" Then hrs = hrs + 12

        Application.EnableEvents = False
            .Clear
            .Value = TimeSerial(hrs, mins, 0)
            .NumberFormat = "[$-en-US]h:mm AM/PM;@"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

This will result in true Excel time values with the correct format.